# When phone is offline GCM stores a LIST of messages or only the last one, just like APNS?

Tags: android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

When phone is offline GCM stores a LIST of messages or only the last one, just like APNS?

I've read a lot about it, but as the documentation says:
1. The GCM connection server enqueues and stores the message if the device is offline.
2. When the device is online, the GCM connection server **sends the message to the device.**

this part 'sends the message to the device' is confusing me. Does it deliver the **list** of messages?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the topic but would expect that messages being received when phone is offline are handled the exact same way as online ones as soon as the Internet connection is restored. No list but sent one by one to your receiver where you need to handle them.

Comment: Tks for your response harism. I used the term 'list' as a bunch of messages sent one by one. In contrast, Apple stores only the last message for a device, and delivers it as soon as the device is online. I'm not certain if google acts the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on some options you can set when sending messages from your server.
There are two things to keep in mind here: the `collapse_key` and the `time_to_live` settings.

The collapse key is used in [send-to-sync messages](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#adv), as opposed to messages with payload. As mentioned by @NickT, you use collapse keys if you only want the latest message under the same collapse key to be sent to the client device when the device comes back online. Messages with payload, on the other hand, always get delivered.

The time_to_live setting is important in the case of offline client devices. It allows you to specify how long a message stays in  the GCM server while waiting for the device to go online. It has a default value of 4 weeks. If you set it to a lower value and the device does not go online in that span, GCM may discard that particular message.

For more details on these, refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server-ref.html#send-downstream) page.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. It's need to differ the two attributes. The link referred is very helpful as well.

Comment: Koh, do you know how it works on Apple APNS? Is there a corresponding 'collapse_key' or 'send-to-sync' ?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the collapse_key to a different value for each message, then they are all (up to a maximum number) are all delivered. If the collapse_keys all have the same value, then only the latest is delivered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it with some tests.